# Installing software when Internet not working

Tags: networking, software-installation

The Internet is not working on my new HP Pavilion laptop (machine A). From what I read, I might be able to cure the problem by installing some extra packages on A. I'm now running on Machine B. On B I can do **apt-get install blah**. So how would I obtain and install **blah** on A, presumably using a memory stick to transfer it from B?

**Edit:**

My response to the ccomment below, the `ifconfig` output is:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 48:ba:4e:52:aa:7f
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0
txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 
txqueuelen:1 RX bytes:12784 (12.7 KB) TX bytes:12784 (12.7 KB)
```

I've learned that on my machine, neither wireless nor wired works on Kubuntu 14.04.5. But on 16.04, wireless works but wired does not. From poking around I've learned that the problem has to do with the Realtek drivers, which probably need to be replaced. (I want to run 14.04.5, not 16.04; in brief, the reason for that is that 14.04 is the last version of Kubuntu that supports different wallpaper on different desktops.) Atleast I've ascertained that I don't have a hardware problem. Finding and installing the corrected Realtek drivers is a challenge by itself, but at least I have a path for installing them (I think).

Comment: Paul, you mistakenly wrote an edit for marko answer, not for your question. I copied it for you, however please check there an **edit** under every post either a question or answer.  To keep Ask Ubuntu clean, keep important info in the original post (the question) .

Comment: `eth0` is there, but you do not have an IP address. Check your Ethernet cable to the router / modem, replace the cable, and run `sudo dhclient`. You will not get Internet until eth0 is assigned an IP address and even then if going through a router, you need to check cable between router to modem but this part is not related with the fact that the router isn't giving you an IP address. It appears to be a cable / router issue.

Answer (score 1):

Download the package on the following Ubuntu site:
[Ubuntu-Package-Site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

Then transfer it via usb,... and install the package the following way:

```
sudo apt install ./name-of-package.deb
```

Don't install via the *dpkg* command, since apt will not recognize it!

If you are using an older apt-get version you have to move the package into the /var/cache/apt/archives directory and install it. Maybe you also have to download other packages to fullfill all dependencies.

BTW: Your internet connection seems to be ok, the card is  up.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was a bad connector on the cable.  That accounts for the failure of wired connections, of course.  It doesn't account for the failure of wireless on 14.04.5, but that's an easier problem since wireless does work on later versions (and I don't absolutely need it anyway).  There's plenty of stuff online about *that* problem.  I wanted to post this right away so no one wastes time on the problem I've now solved.

Comment: Good work :) To keep things neat, you can post a new question about the wireless drivers if it's really important and we'll see what we can do. Otherwise, you can just buy a USB-Wifi adapter with the word Linux on the compatibility list but pay attention to the kernel version. Then Google the model name along with the word "Linux" and see what people say :)

Answer (score 0):

You  need to download the deb packages offline, transfer them to UFD and then using the `gdebi` command (not `dpkg`) install them - `sudo gdebi <packane_name>` and if the package has any dependencies, `gdebi` will not install the package and it will tell you what else you need to download. One of the sites to help you find the required package name is pkgs.org. If you have already installed the packages on your existing machine, you can look in: `/var/cache/apt/archives` and copy the deb files.

Why isn't your Internet working? Could you please post your output of `ifconfig -a`? You can edit your question and post the output. **Warning**: This step will reveal your IP address (if any).

Comment: I'm having a problem in answering your question - my answer exceeds the length limit for comments.  But to answer one part:

Comment: You can click the Edit button of your original post and post your output there. Make sure you enclose it with the {} tags.