# How to remove ntp without internet connection?

Tags: apt, ntp, systemd-timesyncd

i was asked to sync ubuntu 20 via ntp.
usually im using systemd-timesync for this mission.
on this pc i did timedatectrl and got:

```
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Mon 2021-03-08 10:24:24 -05
           Universal time: Mon 2021-03-08 15:24:24 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2021-03-08 13:23:56
                Time zone: America/Bogota (-05, -0500)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

then i see ntp is also installed (btw is this the default for ubuntu 20 now?)
so i downloaded the systemd-timesyncd rpm moved it to this pc then run:

```
~$ sudo dpkg -i systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb
dpkg: regarding systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb containing systemd-timesyncd:
 systemd-timesyncd conflicts with time-daemon
  ntp provides time-daemon and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing systemd-timesyncd
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

the conflicting package is ntp so i try to remove it:

```
~$ sudo apt remove ntp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libopts25 sntp
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  systemd-timesyncd
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ntp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  systemd-timesyncd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 256 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,778 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 systemd-timesyncd amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'il.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'il.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

The following packages will be REMOVED:
ntp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
systemd-timesyncd

but there is no internet connection so apt cant download and install systemd-timesyncd and then it exit.

any idea how to deal with this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: its more about how to remove ntp while offline then how to offline install

Comment: It's the installation of timesyncd that's your problem, not removal of ntp - the issue is that the two are inverse dependent of each other - timesyncd will not install before ntp is removed. So you need to install offline as well.

Comment: this the result of offline install: sudo dpkg -i systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb
dpkg: regarding systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb containing systemd-timesyncd:
 systemd-timesyncd conflicts with time-daemon
  ntp provides time-daemon and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing systemd-timesyncd
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb

Comment: can i force apt\dpkg to ignore the conflict ?   can i fool apt and copy the deb into /var/cache/apt ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing software when Internet not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022924/installing-software-when-internet-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded `systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb`,
moved it to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`
ran `apt remove ntp -y`

all good now